# Angular JS isolated scope not working on directives with service calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am developing an directive where the content changes based on the attribute. So if I am having more than one directive in a page, isolated scope is not working, that is two directives are having same values. This is happening only when there is service calls in the directives and isolated scope works when there is no services and promises.

**Directive**

```
.directive('ex', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<div>Test{{test}}</dic>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if(attr.label == 'dir1') {
            scope.test = 'Directive 1';
        }
        if(attr.label == 'dir2') {
            scope.test = 'Directive 2';
        }
    }
}
})
```

and the HTML is

```
<ex label="directive1"></ex>
<ex label="directive2"></ex>
```

**Output**

```
Directive 1
Directive 2
```

This works perfectly, But when I am having a `http` service call in the directive and if the scope value depends on it, I am getting a wrong output like

`Directive 1 Directive 1`

Please help me to find out why isolated scope is not working while using service calls in a directive.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

**Directive Code with $http**

```
.directive('ex', ['Service', function(Service) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<div>Test{{test}}</dic>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        Service.getData(attr.label).then(function(response) {
          if(response.data.value == 'Testing') {
            scope.test = 'Directive 1';
          } else {
            scope.test = 'Directive 2';
          }
        })

    }
}
}])
```

Comment: Not sure what this line mean " But when I am having a http service call in the directive and if the scope value depends on it, I am getting a wrong output like". Can you add some code around it too.

Comment: @Chandermani - An edit has been made, please check

Comment: @vishnu, have you checked that `Service.getData` actually returns different  `data.value` in each case?

Comment: @NewDev - Yes, it returns different value. I have checked

Comment: Show us the service, we cannot guess without seeing what it does.

Comment: Change my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/y5z5dmg6/) for your problem. So far I have not seen any issues yet. Both `dir1` and `dir2` execute `getData` method from `Service` and change both `scope.test` into `Directive 1` because both `response.data.value` is `Testing`